# Election Voting -- Why can I DOWNVOTE a candidate?

Tags: support, election, voting, down-votes

I'm a little curious as to why users on the moderator election page can downvote a candidate.  This actually does not make sense to me.  Is this a bug? or a feature? and why.

Comment: Why not? In the primaries it shows your *utter* dissapproval of the candidate in question

Comment: to be honest, i want to be able to throw shoes at them. :(

Comment: I wish I could downvote one twice.  :P

Answer (score 11):

It is a feature.

- Upvote is approval.
- No vote neutral.
- Downvote is disapproval.

This gives an overall sense of how the Server Fault community and the wider Stack Exchange users feel about a particular candidate.

Comment: So voting is more of a confidence indicator than a standard voting situation.

Comment: At this stage yes. From tomorrow (Friday 27/11) at 20:00 UTC the top 10 candidates will advance to the election proper.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Iain's answer, to make it to the <s>second</s> Election round, I believe the candidate needs to have a positive *net vote count*. That is, more people approve than disapprove of the candidate.

Comment: It seems that this is not true, at least 2 people in the election had overall negative scores.

Comment: Did they make it to the next round though?

Comment: [I'll give that comment the contempt it deserves](http://serverfault.com/election?cb=1)

Comment: @BigHomie For posterity, no. They didn't.

Comment: @Iain I'm on SE mobile, easier to just ask the question :)

Comment: @sysadmin1138 I see two people who had net negative vote count in the election.

Comment: @Iain my mistake, I was thinking about the election phase, not the true second (primary) phase. I've update my answer.

Comment: @Iain Net-negative is a bit different than a value showing as -1. We had one of those in the primary, that candidate didn't make the general.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Nope. the answer here says net positive which is wrong.  The value showing as -1 is SE being `pink-and-fluffy` and not showing a much bigger negative total that 2 candidates have. The candidate that didn't make it to the primary effectively came 11th in the primary.

Comment: Still wrong. The 2 candidates showing -1 at the end of the primary who got to the election proper had +19/-77 and +25/-81. They look like overall negative values to me. The one that failed to get through had +32/-165 and is therefore quite clearly the least fragrant of the candidates. All 3 show as -1 unless you expand the voting, you can see it clearly if you check out the [primary tab](http://serverfault.com/election/4?tab=primary)

Comment: @Iain I don't see any primary tab on that bikeroutetoaster.com site.  :p

Comment: hahahahah no you know where I cycled at the weekend :) @Zoredache